# How to run deployed ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am creating a default ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application in Visual Studio 2010. I am then deploying this application to a directory on an IIS server. 
I am able to run the default app fine in visual studio. However this is the error get when I try to run the app on the server.

```
Server Error in '/apps/myapp' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration> 

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

After adding

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have a new error:

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 28:         <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 29:         <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 30:         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 31:       </assemblies>
Line 32:     </compilation> 

Source File: D:\Data\Intranet\Apps\icaps\web.config    Line: 30 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Data/Intranet/Apps/icaps/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\Data\Intranet\Apps\icaps\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Data\Intranet\Apps\icaps\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/apps_icaps/d8535ca2/6aefb703/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/apps_icaps/d8535ca2/6aefb703/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Data/Intranet/Apps/icaps/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Data/Intranet/Apps/icaps/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/apps_icaps/d8535ca2/6aefb703/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/apps_icaps/d8535ca2/6aefb703/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Data/Intranet/Apps/icaps/bin/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Data/Intranet/Apps/icaps/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the error? You need to do what it says.

Comment: Have you installed ASP.NET MVC Distributable on this server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error System.Web.Mvc is missing. Check the bin folder of the site on your web server and make sure this assembly exists.

**Predeep** linked to a relevant article for making sure the necessary assemblies deploy to your bin on publish.

[haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

EDIT:
Also in visual studio make sure the property CopyLocal on the assembly in question is set to True.

Comment: There was an additional link on the suggested page by Pradeep, it contained the solution. Here is the link: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

The article states "Select the aforementioned three assemblies and in the Properties dialog, set Copy Local to True." This resolved the issue!

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It means you have an error, and you need to modify your Web.config like IIS is telling you to do so that you can actually see the exception that is being thrown.

To be absolutely clear, you want to change the `customErrors` element in your web.config to this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This should be a comment - explaining how to find out what the error is isn't a solution to the problem.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem then?

Comment: It's impossible to say, which is exactly why *this should be a comment*.

Comment: So I add the code suggested and now this is the error I get.
     
Line 30:         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Comment: You have not deployed MVC and other related assemblies. Refer this article for more details - http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx.

Comment: I'm sure there's more to the error than just the line number. I have a hunch that it's complaining that MVC isn't installed on the server you've deployed to.

Comment: @Pradeep is correct you need to make sure these assemblies are being deployed.